# What's the meaning of the slash in crontab?

Tags: cron

I have seen a crontab record in system.

```
0-55/5 * * * *   root  <command>
```

I read the `crontab -e` example files and I know the first position stands for minute. But I cannot figure out the meaning of `/` (slash) there. Could anyone explain the meaning to me?

Comment: `man 5 crontab` has explanations too.

Comment: @jw013 thanks for correcting! @Mat Thanks. Buy the way, how to go to next page with `man`? I read through `man crontab` and through it was the end.

Comment: @yangchenyun, it's not the next page.  It's another section.  `man crontab` brings up the first entry for `crontab`, which is for the `crontab` _command_ in section 1.  Towards the end of that manpage, it says `SEE ALSO crontab(5)`.  That tells you that you can use `man 5 crontab` to read the `crontab` entry in section 5, which describes the format of the `crontab` _file_.

Comment: @cjm Thanks for this information. I was always wondering about those `(3)` thing in the `SEE ALSO` section!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The forward slash is used in conjunction with ranges to specify step values.

`0-55/5 * * * *` means your command will be executed every five minutes (0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 55).

`0-55/5` is the same as `*/5`.

Comment: what about */31 on the minute field. Does it means the scrip will on on 0 and 31 or 1 and 31?

Comment: @DanielShen It would run on 0 and 31 on every hour.

Comment: why do */5 * * * * instead of 5 * * * * ? Are they not the same?

Comment: @Andrew `5 * * * *` will run at five minutes after the top of the hour, every hour (i.e., once an hour). `*/5 * * * *` will run every five minutes (i.e., twelve times an hour)

Comment: I would like to suggest to @purplexa to propose that additional clarification in the answer. I tried but unfortunately the edit queue is full now

Answer (score 1):

I've found an useful info from the official documentation:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range
> with `/<number>` specifies skips of the number's value through the
> range. For example, `0-23/2`  can  be  used  in  the  hours  field  to   specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`). Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say *every two hours*, just use `*/2`.
>
> ― `man 5 crontab` - 4th Berkeley Distribution - 19 April 2010

In short, all of these are valid syntax:

```
0-55/5 * * * *
\       \ \ \ \- every day of week
 \       \ \ \-- every month
  \       \ \--- every day of month
   \       \---- every hours
    \----------- from minute 0 to 55, using a step of 5 minutes
```

That means minute 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 45 and 55 included.